# What's the difference between the use of numpy.linalg.inverse and reciprocal?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am currently working on the spectral gradient method. Now I have developed two similar algorithms, but apparently, when I thought they yield the same results, they actually return different values after some iterations.

Here's the variable

```
v (vector at kth iteration)
v_1 (vector at k+1th iteration)
g (gradient at kth iteration)
g_1 (gradient at k+1th iteration)
```

The first algorithm is as follows:

```
def spectral_grad1(
    v: np.ndarray, v_1: np.ndarray,
    g: np.ndarray, g_1: np.ndarray
    ) -> np.ndarray:

    s = v_1 - v
    y = g_1 - g

    sT_y = s.T@y
    sT_s = s.T@s

    if s.T_s > s.T_y:
        s1 = s**4
        s2 = s**2
        w_k = (sT_s - sT_y) / s1.sum()
        B_k  = np.array([1. / (1.+ w_k*i) for i in s2])
        return np.diag(B_k)

    return np.identity(len(s)) #rescaling

direction = np.negative(np.linalg.inv(B) @ g)
```

On the other hand, here is the second algorithm:

```
def spectral_grad2(
    v: np.ndarray, v_1: np.ndarray,
    g: np.ndarray, g_1: np.ndarray
    ) -> np.ndarray:
    
    s = v_1 - v
    y = g_1 - g
    
    sT_y = s.T@y
    sT_s = s.T@s

    if sT_s <= sT_y:
        return np.identity(len(v)) # Rescaling

    s1 = s**4
    s2 = s**2
    w_k = (sT_s - sT_y) / s1.sum()
    B_k = 1. + w_k*s2
    return np.diag(B_k) # Diagonal matrix of B

direction = -(B @ g)
```

If you look at these two algorithms, the only difference is the `B_k` and the computation of `direction`.

I'm sorry as I can't give you much data to reproduce this since this is just part of the gradient descent algorithm. What I'm more curious is about what gives the `B_k` and `direction` in both algorithms to have different result?

**Edit**

I wish to find the inverse of `B_k`. So any insight about the use of reciprocal or `np.linalg.inv` would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Reciprocal of the elements and the inverse of a matrix are not the same operations. Assuming *B* is somehow returned by your function.

Comment: I'm starting to see the 'seem-to-be-small-but-very-significant' difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of these you effectively use:

```
diag([1. / (1.+ w_k*i) ...])
```

and in the other

```
linalg.inv(diag(1. + w_k*s2))
```

Note that the theoretical inverse of a diagonal matrix **is** the reciprocal diagonal matrix.  But `linalg.inv` cannot know it’s input is diagonal and thus the numerical inverse produced is likely to have some very small non zero values off-diagonal.

Comment: So just as @Michael Szczesny said, it will surely yield different result since both reciprocal and inverse are not the same?

Comment: Thanks @donkopotamus, this is truly thrilling as just by this slight difference, my results are totally different.